# Why are breaking points not being hit?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, visual-studio-code

I started to use Linux a while ago, and I'm trying to run some old codes that were made for windows. They are running, but I can't Debug then, the breaking points aren't being hit. I've seen that many problems with this are related to not adding the "-g" at the "MakeFile", but not seems to be my case. I'm using Vscode, my breaking points get like this during the debugging

[image]

Here is my Make file:

```
    CC=gcc
    CFLAGS= -o -W -ggdb -g 
    LDFLAGS= -lm -lstdc++
    OBJFILES = main.o Funcoes.o Mat_Vet.o rotinas_matematicas.o Classes.o SME5720.o
    TARGET = ss
    
    all: $(TARGET)
    
    $(TARGET): $(OBJFILES)
            $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) $(LDFLAGS)
    
    clean:
        rm -f $(OBJFILES) $(TARGET) *~
```

Here's my json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
        
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/ss",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Breakpoints make sense only when you run your code under a debugger. Do you?

Comment: `CFLAGS= -o ...` The `-o` option here makes no sense.

Comment: Yes I run my code under a debugger

Comment: Does it stop at entry when you debug?

Comment: Yes, it ignores just the breaking points that I pu.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem by changing the "MakeFile", I don't know why it works. If anyone could say why. Here is my new makefile:

```
output: main.o Classes.o Funcoes.o Mat_Vet.o rotinas_matematicas.o SME5720.o
    g++ main.o Classes.o Funcoes.o Mat_Vet.o rotinas_matematicas.o SME5720.o -o output

main.o:main.cpp
    g++ -c -g main.cpp

Classes.o: Classes.cpp Classes.h
    g++ -c -g Classes.cpp

Funcoes.o: Funcoes.cpp Funcoes.h
    g++ -c -g Funcoes.cpp

Mat_Vet.o: Mat_Vet.cpp Mat_Vet.h
    g++ -c -g Mat_Vet.cpp

rotinas_matematicas.o: rotinas_matematicas.cpp rotinas_matematicas.h
    g++ -c -g rotinas_matematicas.cpp
SME5720.o: SME5720.cpp SME5720.h
    g++ -c -g SME5720.cpp   

clean:
    rm *.o output
```